# how write complex numbers to one csv file in each row?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, fft

I want to **to store a complex number of each image** which is generated by using **Fast Fourier transform** which is of type **complex 128**.
 the code is as follow:

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np
bloodVessal=[]
for file in glob.glob('/home/raviraj/PycharmProjects/Diabetic/testing/*.jpeg'):
    img=cv2.imread(file)
    cv2.imshow('file',img)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (255, 255), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # split image
    b, g, r = cv2.split(img)
    cv2.imshow("green window", g)

    # creating CLAHE histogram
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    claheImg = clahe.apply(g)
    cv2.imshow('clahe image', claheImg)

    # Edge Detection
    edge = cv2.Canny(claheImg, 165, 40)
    cv2.imshow('Edge detection ', edge)

    # FFT
    f = np.fft.fft2(edge)

    np.savetxt('/home/raviraj/PycharmProjects/Diabetic/testing/blood vessel.csv', f, delimiter=',')

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

this code is creating a CSV file with **255 rows and 255 column**. I want just **one column and 200 rows**.In which each row contain data of each image in just **single line**.

Comment: Can you skip all the `cv2` code and show us the array you want to save (or at least a subset)?  Is it the `f`?  `bloodVessal` list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to save the list `bloodVessel` to a plain text file. To do so with a single column, append the following after the loop:

```
np.savetxt('data.csv',bloodVessel,delimiter=',')
```

This will create a file called `data.csv` that looks like,

```
(0.000000000000000000e+00+1.000000000000000000e+00j)
(5.000000000000000000e+00+3.000000000000000000e+00j)
```

If you want the real and imaginary parts in separate columns (and want the comma delimiter):

```
np.savetxt('data.csv',[np.real(bloodVessel),np.imag(bloodVessel)],delimiter=',')
```

which will instead create a file that looks like,

```
0.000000000000000000e+00,+1.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00,+3.000000000000000000e+00
```

I would also recommend preallocating `bloodVessel` as a numpy array of complex type rather than appending to a list to foster good habits.

**IN RESPONSE TO THE COMMENT AND THE APPARENT REWRITE OF THE QUESTION**

Before you were saving your Fourier coefficients in the list `bloodVessel` by appending. At the moment, I'm not sure how you're editing your code. However, if your Fourier data is now NOT just a single complex value, then you can still do what was mentioned above, just save the coefficient that you want in the list rather than the whole array of coefficients.

That is, go from `bloodVessel.append(f)` to `bloodVessel.append(f[0])`, where I am assuming you want to only save the first coefficient.

Comment: thank you so much, sir, you helped me a lot. but there is one new problem can you help me with that it. I am updating my code section read it. Actually, I am reading each image and using fast Fourier transformation each time after calculating that value I want to store that big value in just one row, similarly, I want to store 200 complex number in just one row by row. so that the table will have 200 rows each has complex128 type value.

Comment: You shouldn't update the original code posting like that, instead either make a new section of your question that is clearly identified as a response, or ask a new question!